# Google Chrome: Prevent desktop link to always open a new tab

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, desktop, url

Is it possible to force google chrome to always open a windows desktop link within the same tab?

This is the target used for the desktop link:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://superuser.com
```

If the link is clicked multiple times it will always spawn a new tab. Is there a way to prevent this without using a chrome plugin? Is there a start parameter for chrome for windows that specifies a target like a HTML link?

Comment: Which link is clicked multiple times? Any link I click in Chrome is opened in the same tab.

Comment: The windows desktop link is clicked multiple times. Links within a web page are opened within the same tab. Within a web page it is possible to name a unique target via the target attribute of a HTML link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately what your asking doesn't exist:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/fkx4NoFdHCo/LYRsLpn3WUwJ

As per the other answer and in addition, you can kill and restart chrome with a link.

If you want multiple pages to open in multiple tabs you can add them in a list like so

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://superuser.com http://superuser.com
```

I have tried a couple of alternatives which have not worked to see if I can find a bypass that just hasn't been documented including

```
1:http://superuser.com
"New Tab":http://superuser.com
1,http://superuser.com
#http://superuser.com
```

I am surprised there is no system setup like this but I guess in a tabbed world, why new windows? and why over the top of an existing tab? There is a tag you can add in html for a page to open on a named tab (target=location) but that would not be from the desktop. I am not aware of other browsers having this functionality either but please prove me wrong on that one.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot - Google Chrome will not assume that any existing tab is still in its
initial state as when the URL was initially invoked.

If this is a problem, you might stop and restart Chrome :

```
taskkill /IM chrome.exe
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://superuser.com
```